# How can I subset a data frame by a specific year and two specific months?

Tags: date, format, subset, as.date

I have been subsetting my data set based on year and month using:

```
sub2007 <- subset(Data, format(Date, "%Y") == "2007" & format(Data, "%m") == "04")
```

Which has been working fine.  However, how can I select multiple months? I have tried several things but it keeps giving me a data frame with zero obs.  Any help welcome.

I have tried:

```
sub2007 <- subset(Data, format(Date, "%Y") == "2007" & format(Date, "%m") == "04" & format(Date, "%m") == "05")
```

and

```
2007sub <- subset(Data, as.Date(Date) >= "01/04/2007" & as.Date(Date) < "01/06/2007")
```

Ideally I would like to select individual months, and not a between two dates type command.

Data looks like:

```
| ID        | Date       | Between    |
--------------------------------------
| D12222222 | 30/11/2007 | 0          |
| D12222222 | 02/04/2007 | 278        |
| F33333333 | 24/05/2007 | 0          |
| F33333333 | 06/05/2007 | 5279       |
| F33333333 | 30/04/2007 | 267        |
```

Comment: Can you questionify your post please? Normally users hate to solve/write code just like that... They prefer answering a specific question.

Comment: Sure, hopefully this is in a question enough format now, but let me know if not, thanks.